# Полигиния и полиандрия - есть ли более общий термин?

Tags: терминология, термины

Даже не знаю, относится ли этот вопрос именно к русскому языку, а не к социологии, например. Но откуда-то надо отталкиваться в поисках ответа на вопрос...

В общем, интересует, существует ли термин, объединяющий в себе *полигинию* (многоженство) и *полиандрию* (многомужество), т.е. обозначающий узаконенные брачные отношения между минимум двумя мужчинами и минимум двумя женщинами?

Да, в русском языке существует понятие *шведской семьи*, в которой может состоять по несколько партнёров каждого пола, однако оно имеет несерьёзную, полушутливую коннотацию, если так можно выразиться.

Answer (score 1):

Если отталкиваться от понятия "шведской семьи", то такого термина нет. Само это понятие несколько расплывчато (*в наиболее общем понимании - число супругов три и более, пол не важен*), а вы еще говорите о каких-то "узаконенных" отношениях...

> т.е. обозначающий узаконенные брачные отношения между минимум двумя
>   мужчинами и минимум двумя женщинами?

А вот это - пожалуйста. **Групповой брак.** Термин, если не ошибаюсь введен еще Энгельсом - в работе "Происхождение семьи, частной собственности и государства". Хотя само понятие использовалось задолго до того.

По некоторым источникам "групповой брак" и есть узаконенный синоним "шведской семьи", но, полагаю, между терминами есть разница, гораздо большая, чем просто стилистическая. Причину я уже назвал. Термин "шведская семья" не только "несерьезен", но и расплывчат.

Для определения групповых семейных отношений может использоваться и термин ***"полиамория"***  - вот его можно считать аналогом группового брака, но с оговоркой, что  он узаконенен только на основании личных обязательств всех перед всеми членами группы.

Есть еще термин ***"поливерность"***  - в нем обязательным условием являются интимные отношения всех со всеми (с учетом пола), но не на стороне. При простом групповом браке (и полиамории) такое не предполагается, отношения остаются избирательными - но строго внутри группы.

Термин же *"полигамность"* - в лучшем случае частный случай всех перечисленных. Поскольку он предполагает наличие нескольких супругов у **одного** лица.Гарем - типичный тому пример. Мусульманин имеет нескольких жен, но мусульманка - только одного 
мужа.

Answer (score 0):

Полига́мия, многобрачие — форма брака, при котором супруг одного пола имеет более одного супруга противоположного пола. Различают два вида полигамии: многожёнство (полигиния) и многомужество (полиандрия).

Comment: «Отношения между минимум двумя мужчинами и минимум двумя женщинами»  — т. е. 2 vs 2 min. Читайте behemothus.